# Is there any way to skip the initial setup of macos bigsur?

Tags: command-line, applescript, macos-big-sur

STR

1. Create a new user on bigsur
2. Login using that user
3. Initial setup required

Need a way to skip the initial setup and directly open the home screen.

Comment: I don't know wether it works on BigSur, but for Mojave solved here https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/364495/can-i-suppress-the-setup-assistant-when-creating-new-users-on-macos

Comment: I don't know wether it works on BigSur, but for Mojave solved here https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/364495/can-i-suppress-the-setup-assistant-when-creating-new-users-on-macos

Comment: I don't know wether it works on BigSur, but for Mojave solved here https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/364495/can-i-suppress-the-setup-assistant-when-creating-new-users-on-macos

Comment: I don't know wether it works on BigSur, but for Mojave solved here
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/364495/can-i-suppress-the-setup-assistant-when-creating-new-users-on-macos